# Eclipse RCP Jython - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse-rcp, pydev, jython, noclassdeffounderror

I'm developing an eclipse RCP application.
I have a Jar with some classes I want to use in Jython.
On startup I'm adding the Jython console with initial commands that add the jar by sending the command `sys.path.append(some .jar file path)`.

I can use the classes in the Jar and their functions execute.
But one function I use there eventually throws a `NoClassDefError`.
The class its looking for is in the Jar (I build that jar using Ant and the class is really inside another Jar but its included in the build).

I can invoke `import problematic_class from some_package` and then use the class,
but when I call the function that eventually tries to use the class (in code) I get the exception.

What can be the problem?

**Details:**

The classes I get the exceptions for are: `org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils` and `org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/impl/CTTableColumnsImpl$1TableColumnList`.

The jars that include those classes are included in the build process of the Jar I give to `sys.path.append...`

I can do (without any exceptions):

`from org.apache.commons.lang3 import StringUtils`

`StringUtils.strip("Smth", "S")`

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is kind of hard to follow. Can you provide an example of the code in which the exception occurs? Does the exception happen every time? Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually solved this by adding the jar file to the Runtime classpath under plugin.xml.
Didn't know there were two classpaths.. So should I answer myself or delete the question?